# Being interested/Interested in nitroglycerine, over the years, Alfred himself performed…?

Tags: participles, nonfinite-verbs

**Sample test:**
_________ (interest) in nitroglycerine, over the years, Alfred himself performed so many experiments to make sure it could be put into practical use in construction work.

The given answer is "Interested"

**My thread:**
I was wondering if "Being interested" was also Ok, which means "Because he was interested in…"

**Question：**
Is “Being interested” acceptable? If so, which is a better answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer that the test wants is always the best answer. *Being Interested* is less a form of *interest* than simply *interested*.

Comment: I agree with @YosefBaskin on the “best” answer for a test. But I’d also note that I would, myself, say, “Being interested…” in speech.  Or “Having been interested…”  if one of his experiments had gone awry.

Comment: Putting "being" at the start makes the structure of the sentence clearer: it is immediately obvious what kind of clause you're reading. But "Interested" is still valid.